# Can I Test mobile/DTH recharge service without actual money?

Tags: manual-testing, functional

How Testing is done in e-payment applications?

Do they use actual money in order to test all payment services.If not,are there any techniques/methods to test.

For Eg:Mobile recharge in Paytm or in Freecharge.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do the testing with test credit cards which is available online.

Usually, the test system or QA system will have the test service for the payment service it will allow using the test credit cards. If it is not you can validate them in the production environment with test card to check the failure behavior.

For the positive behavior of the application need to use the real cards as per my knowledge.